# "До тех пор пока..."

Tags: пунктуация

Когда запятая ставится перед всем союзом "до тех пор пока", а когда - перед словом "пока"?
Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В Русской грамматике ваш сложный подчинительный союз выглядит таким образом: **до тех пор пока не** (расчленяемый вариант союза **пока не**). Частица **не** является структурным элементом самого союза и, независимо от позиции, не имеет отрицательного значения. Во всех примерах, найденных мной в Русской грамматике, сложный союз **до тех пор пока не** разделяется запятой, например: *Сердце любит до тех пор, пока не истратит своих сил* (Гончаров).
Думаю, это потому, что вторая часть этого сложного союза - **пока не**, а не **что, как, чтобы**.